# Rendering PartialView in EditorTemplate for Orchard CMS

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

I'm trying to create a module for Orchard CMS. 
This specific module has a List (FAQS), and I wanted the EditorTemplate to be dynamically fillable.
Click a button, and 2 new fields for the next FAQ gets added.

This is done through a PartialView that gets called for every question that is in the list. When there are questions in the list, it loads dynamically just fine. But as soon as I want to add new questions it stops working, telling me it can't find the page I want to render.

The code for the editor template:

```
<fieldset>
    <div style="border: 1px solid black">
        <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Title, T("Title"))
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Title, new { @class = "text medium" })
        </div>
        <ul id="FAQs" style="list-style-type: none">
            @if (Model.FAQList == null || Model.FAQList.Count == 0) {
            } else {
                <li>FAQS</li>
                foreach (FAQ faq in Model.FAQList) {
                    Html.RenderPartial("FAQItem", faq);
                }
            }
        </ul>
        <a id="addAnother" href="#" onclick="test();">Add Question</a>
</fieldset>
```

And the test() function

```
function test() {
            $.get('FAQItem', function (data) {
                $("#FAQs").append(data);
            });
        }
```

The EditorTemplate is under Views/EditorTemplates/FAQ and the FAQItem is under Views/FAQItem.

For as far as I can see, is that the test function is trying to request the PartialView from another place then the Html.RenderPartial() does.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I'm reading this right and `$.get('FAQItem',...` there is to retrieve via AJAX, you'll need to give it a fully qualified URL which includes the specific controller which contains `FAQItem`. This URL would be created with a Razor call like

```
@Url.Action("FAQItem", "<Controller>", new { area = "<Module>" })
```